# Hold string in textblock when switching pages

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a WP8 app and want to hold a text in a textblock when I switch to another page.

So when I come back at the page with the textblock, the text must be still there.
Does anyone know a way for doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at Isolated Storage and/or Page State?

Comment: I think that's for if you want to work with a server, or am I wrong?

Comment: No, no server necessary for either of those.  One of them should suit your purposes.

Comment: Could you show me an example please? Sorry, but I'm a beginner...

Answer (score 0):

(Example is in C#, sorry ...)

One way of persisting data is to use [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), specifically [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  A simple example of how to do this is:

1. On the Page's "OnNavigatedFrom" event, add data to storage
2. On the Page's "OnNavigatedTo" event, retrieve from storage

---

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

   // textBlock is a TextBlock defined in XAML.
   if (!settings.Contains("userData"))
       settings.Add("userData", textBlock.Text);
   else
       settings["userData"] = textBlock.Text;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

   if (settings.Contains("userData"))
       textBlock.Text = (string)settings["userData"];
}
```